# PHP Array is filled with data, but can't return values

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an array $presettings
print_r($presettings); outputs:

```
Array (
  [0] => stdClass Object (
    [uuid] => xxx-1ef8-aac6-xxx-xxx
    [name] => etime
    [owner] => eder112T Resident
    [online] => 1
    [channel] => 63b525ae-xxx-3555-1c74-xxx
    [owner_uuid] => a371751c-eb77-xxx-899c-xxx
    [simname] => Plainfield
    [slurl] => xxx://xxx/xx/xx/243/24/xx/?title=xx
    [design] => 2
    [msg_oftheday] => two
    [machine_name] => one
    [autopay] =>
    [autolog_leave] => 
    [autolog_offline] => 
    [allow_activation] =>
  )
)
```

and now i want to get a special key:

```
echo "test output : "$presettings['machine_name']." testend";
outputs "" (nothing).
```

my method look like this

```
function preloadSettingsFromMYSQL($ownername,$prim_uuid)
{
    $result = $this->instance->get_rows("SELECT * FROM etime_rims where owner='".$ownername."' AND uuid='".$prim_uuid."'");
    return $result;
}
```

$result is an object array, also tried it with $presettings->machine_name, did not work too.

where is the error?
thank you.

Comment: $presettings[0]->machine_name

Comment: OMG WORKED thanks, but why is this?

Comment: You have an explanation in the two answers below.

Comment: because get_rows returns an array of objects, so [0] will return the first object, and ->machine_name, again because it is an object and not a single [key]=value array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely in the print_r result, you can see that there is a 0 there, meaning that those values aren't directly in `$presettings`, but actually in the first element of `$presettings`.

Just try:

```
$presettings[0]->machine_name
```

Comment: Classic mistake for beginners, not a big deal. :)

Answer (score 0):

You object is multi dimensional so just add a level

```
$presettings[0]->machine_name;
```

As side note you have an object here and not array do don't try to access  alues with scopes.

Answer (score 0):

In your array, you have `stdClass Object` at index `0`. You're looking to access the object's variables, which is a slightly different syntax than arrays:

```
echo $presettings[0]->machine_name;
```